# XAML Datepicker create Behavior to avoid 0001 year

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two datepickers, and these datepickers accepts `01/01/0001` (They fetch data From, and To dates), the problem is, I have the following error:`"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."`

Is there any way to attach a behavior that when, if the user writes a date below `01/01/1753` it overwrites it as `01/01/1753`?

Comment: Why don't you do this in your data access layer before you execute the SQL query?

Comment: Because a behavior would be a more generalized solution, I have a lot of datepickers and all of them need to have the same Behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `CalendarDateRange` to the `BlackoutDates` property that disables any date before `1753-01-01`:

```
<DatePicker>
    <DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
        <CalendarDateRange Start="0001-01-01" End="1752-12-31" />
    </DatePicker.BlackoutDates>
</DatePicker>
```

You can wrap this in an attached behaviour if you want to:

```
public class Behavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisableDateRangeProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "DisableDateRange", typeof(bool), typeof(Behavior), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnChanged)));

    public static void SetDisableDateRangeProperty(DatePicker element, bool value) =>
        element.SetValue(DisableDateRangeProperty, value);

    public static bool GetDisableDateRangeProperty(DatePicker element) =>
        (bool)element.GetValue(DisableDateRangeProperty);

    private static void OnChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)d;
        dp.BlackoutDates.Add(new CalendarDateRange(new DateTime(0001, 1, 1), new DateTime(1752, 12, 31)));
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
<DatePicker local:Behavior.DisableDateRangeProperty="True" />
```

Comment: It works really well, my question would be the following, is it possible to put the behavior inside the tag <i:Interaction.Behaviors> where i is xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"? how would you set the property?

Comment: @Nickso: Not using this kind of behaviour. Then you should create a Blend behaviour.